# Dropdown shows up on second click - AutoCompleteTextView with a dropdown

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I have  an `AutoCompleteTextView` with a simple dropdown in my `Home.activity` and it works great but Now my app is almost ready to be published, I want to remove some UI glitches, so here's One.
The Dropdown on the `AutoCompleteTextView` contains 8 city names and it looks/works great but on first click on the `AutoCompleteTextview`, the keyboard pops up and then when clicked again ,the dropdown comes.
 I want this dropdown to come on the first click with the Keyboard.
Here's my code of implementation.

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:hint="@string/select_city"
        android:id="@+id/acT1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:background="@drawable/shape1"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.25"
        android:dropDownHeight="155dp"
        android:cursorVisible="false"
        android:maxLines="1"/>

final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(
                this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getResources()
                .getStringArray(R.array.Loc_names));
        textView1 = findViewById(R.id.acT1);
        textView1.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        textView1.setThreshold(1);
        textView1.setCursorVisible(false);
        textView1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                textView1.showDropDown();
                textView1.setCursorVisible(false);
                hideKeyBoard(view);
                selection = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                TastyToast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), selection,
                TastyToast.LENGTH_LONG, TastyToast.SUCCESS);
                imageView.setAlpha(.8f);
            }


        });
        textView1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(final View arg0) {
                textView1.showDropDown();
                textView1.setCursorVisible(true);
                //imageView.setAlpha(.8f);
            }
        });
```

[**Here's the GIF**](https://giphy.com/gifs/3ohhwDnMGpg3lV8j16).

Comment: screenshot of how your dropdown is looking ?

Comment: @PrakhaRam [Here's the GIF](https://giphy.com/gifs/3ohhwDnMGpg3lV8j16).

Comment: what if you don't open the list on double click, instead take this as a feature by autocompletetextview that it will display filtered results for entered query in a dropdown.

Comment: try playing with threshold or "performFiltering" attributes for the dataset you want to display dropdown. else it will show dropdown when you input some characters

Comment: Problem is that it is meant to open on the first click as a spinner.

Comment: It happens because of focus, as when activity started, it's not in focus so this happens and after getting focus, it works in a single click. Problem is if I give it the focus on starting of activity, keyboard automatically pops up which I don't want to have.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156442/discussion-between-prakharam-and-hardik-sharma).

Answer (score 1):

Just add a Focus FALSE and Onclickable TRUE into AutoCompleteTextView

Comment: Try this it will work <AutoCompleteTextView> <requestFocus /><AutoCompleteTextView>

Answer (score 1):

try with ontouch listener

```
textview1.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
            touching = false;
        }else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            touching = true;
            handle event
        }
        return true;
    }
```